# Postgresql problems with postgres_fdw module

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, postgres-fdw

I'm trying, using the PostgreSQL Maestro tool, to reference a foreign key coming from a "local" DB to an other primary key inside an other DB (actually, they're both on the same remote machine).
I've heard about the postgres_fdw module to create a foreign table that act like a copy of the table inside the remote DB, but when I try to execute my query I have this error:

"SQL Error: ERROR: referenced relation "foreign_olo" is not a table".

This is my sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE edb.olo_config (  
primary_key       integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
puntamento        varchar,
mail_contatto_to  varchar,
mail_contatto_cc  varchar,
/* Foreign keys */
CONSTRAINT olo_code
  FOREIGN KEY (olo_code)
  REFERENCES edb.foreign_olo(codice_operatore)
) WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
);
```

foreign_olo is my foreign table created with postgres_fdw.
I have tried to commit an INSERT or a simple SELECT on the foreign_olo table, and all went well, so I can't understand why for the foreign key case it can't be recognized as a table.
Thank you to everyone would give me an hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to enforcing a foreign key constraint:

- An `INSERT` (or `UPDATE` of the FK field) on the child table must check that a parent record exists.
- A `DELETE` (or `UPDATE` of the PK field) on the parent table must check that no child record exists.

Foreign tables can't be referenced by FK constraints, because this second condition is impossible to enforce - there's no way for the remote server to automatically check for records in your local table.

You can implement the first check relatively easily with a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION edb.olo_config_fk_trg() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM edb.foreign_olo
    WHERE codice_operatore = new.olo_code
    FOR KEY SHARE
  )
  THEN
    RAISE foreign_key_violation
      USING MESSAGE = 'edb.foreign_olo.codice_operatore="' || new.olo_code || '" not found';
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER olo_config_fk_trg
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF olo_code ON edb.olo_config
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE edb.olo_config_fk_trg();
```

You can create a similar trigger on the PK table to do the update/delete check, but it will require another foreign table in your other database which points back to your local `olo_config`.